# Excel: Copy formula to every second cell

Tags: excel

I'm not very familiar with excel, so if this is trivial, please forgive me.

I have an excel column like this in Column A:

```
Bread
Milk
Cheese
```

Now I want to copy the contents of A to Column D but I want it to skip a line after each entry like this:

```
Bread

Milk

Cheese
```

Is there a way to do this using a cell formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a formula:

```
=IF(C1="",INDEX($A$2:$A$20,COUNTBLANK($C$1:C1)),"")
```

[image]