# Copy formula vertical in Excel every third row (skip 2 rows and then take the next one)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to copy a formula in excel but only every 3rd row. 
Please see the image as reference:

[image]

And I need this for about 5000 cells so I ideally would be to drag it down but when I do that excel just references the same row instead the next one from Column A

There is an example on how to do this and skip one cell, but in my case I want to skip 2 cells.
The example is:

```
=IF(C1="",INDEX($A$2:$A$20,COUNTBLANK($C$1:C1)),"")
```

and is posted [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40237130/2058726)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From cell `C1` and drag down:**

```
=IF(INT((ROW()+2)/3)=(ROW()+2)/3,INDIRECT("A"&((ROW()+2)/3)),"")
```

Or:

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("A"&(ROW()+2)/3),"")
```

Or non-volatile:

```
=IF(INT((ROW()+2)/3)=(ROW()+2)/3,INDEX($A$1:$A$10,(ROW()+2)/3),"")
```

Or another non-volatile:

```
=IF(MOD((ROW()+2)/3,1)=0,INDEX($A$1:$A$10,(ROW()+2)/3),"")
```

**From cell `C2` and drag down:**

```
=IF(INT((ROW()+1)/3)=(ROW()+1)/3,INDIRECT("A"&((ROW()+1)/3)+1),"")
```

Or:

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("A"&((ROW()+1)/3)+1),"")
```

Or non-volatile:

```
=IF(INT((ROW()+1)/3)=(ROW()+1)/3,INDEX($A$1:$A$10,(ROW()+1)/3),"")
```

Or another non-volatile:

```
=IF(MOD((ROW()+1)/3,1)=0,INDEX($A$1:$A$10,(ROW()+1)/3),"")
```

Comment: OK this is cool, I will mark it as an answer because it solves the issue but the problem is that I used a sample data. Is this possible for the formula to start from C2 instead from C1?. I am definitely marking this as an answer but if you could help me here I would appreciate it much.

Comment: @al1en, If you want to start from `C2` just change the +2 into +1

Comment: I figured it, in my case I needed to change +3 to place it into the right row. Do you know which one of those is faster on performance?

Comment: Pick the non-volatile whenever you can!

Answer (score 1):

If you statically input the value inside C1 as `=A1`

And then procceed from `C4` with following formula:

```
=IF(MOD(COUNTBLANK($B$1:$B6),3)=0, INDEX($A$1:$A$18,MATCH(OFFSET(C4, -3, 0), $A$1:$A$18) + 1), "")
```

Then it will work:

[image]

Comment: Cool idea using `MOD()`, if you don't mind I used that in one of my examples too! +1

Comment: @JvdV yeah feel free to go ahead :) Afterall, I'd like to think of SO as a collaboration!